# Java SWT Centralize absolute composite on screen

Tags: java, swt

I am developing an application and my employer demands that it should have an absolute size (1024 x 768). Is it possible to insert this absolute composite into another composite with fill layout (or any other) and set the absolute layout to be always centralized?

I am fairly new to developing screens, so I'm confused with this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. It is straightforward to set the size and position of a Shell, is that not what you want?

Comment: @gre-449 sorry if it is was not clear.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: I want to have a shell with is size set to fill the screen. And inside this shell, I want a composite (1024x768) always set to be in the center of the screen. Doesn't matter the resolution of the computer who's accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GridLayout` to center the Composite in the Shell.

Something like:

```
Display display = new Display();

Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);

shell.setText("Stack Overflow");

shell.setFullScreen(true);

shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

// Composite, just using a border here to show where it is
Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);

// Center composite in the shell using all available space 
composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

// Something to put in the composite
Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.BEGINNING);
label.setText("Text");

shell.open();

while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
      display.sleep();
  }

display.dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you, Greg. This was exactly what I needed.